# Can I start a 529 plan for a child before the child is born?

Tags: united-states, investing, children, education-savings, 529-plan

[A recent question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8462/strategies-for-putting-away-money-for-a-childs-future-college-etc) got me wondering about this one: Conventional wisdom says "It's never too early to start saving for your kid's college education." But a 529 plan is taken out for a specific person. So what if that person isn't born yet? Is it too early to start saving for your kid's college education (with a 529 plan)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the warning that I've recently read a series of comments to an article "[Why I bought life insurance for my newborn](http://www.myjourneytomillions.com/articles/why-i-will-be-purchasing-life-insurance-on-my-newborn-baby/)," I'd advise against this. You gain little in that 9 months given the very high limits for deposits, and would just be better off waiting till the baby is keeping you up at night. 
As Frazell replied, he is correct. I'd still not do it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can list yourself as the beneficiary and then change it to the child later. You are allowed to change who the account is for at anytime without penalty.

At least this is true for the PA 529 Plan.